# What should I do with the hidden/disabled Administrator account?

Tags: windows, hardening, account-security

In Windows 10, there is the Administrator account that is disabled by default. What should I do with it, with regards to hardening Windows?

I have heard of adding a password to it, but is that necessary if it is set to Disabled?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the password is not set on the disabled account, anyone with remote access could enable the account and use it, no password necessary. You should always set the password so that even when enabled, the account still can't be easily used. However, unless further precautions are taken (such as a BIOS password) anyone with physical access can boot [NT Offline Password Reset](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) from a USB to enable the default admin account as well as blank the password for it.

This link will provide you with some further learning: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2006.01.securitywatch.aspx

Comment: Can the Administrator account be disabled again after the password has been added? Would it wipe the password again when it gets disabled?  Thank you.

Comment: @Smiith It sure can. At the university I work for, we have a disabled admin account on all machines on our network. That way if we can't login with domain credentials, and we need to re-bind the machine to the network, we can enable the local admin account, use the pre-set password, and disable it again when we are done. Here is the windows command `net user administrator /active:no`

Comment: Will there be any disadvantages / advantages to disabling the Administrator account as far as security hardening goes?

Comment: @Smiith Absolutely, the default administrator account has absolute power over your machine, leaving it disabled prevents an attacker from attempting to use the account to log in. They would need to first enable it, making their job much harder. As far as disadvantages, I can't think of any, you shouldn't use that account unless absolutely necessary anyway.

Comment: That is good to know, thank you very much for the info.

Comment: @Smiith I have also edited my answer to include additional reading on the topic.

Comment: I should also check, if I have a regular admin account, and a standard user account, when would the Administrator account password be used if it was enabled?

Comment: @Smiith Assuming that your user accounts are local (and not coming from an active directory domain service) you should never need the Administrator account, because your 'regular admin' account is already local. If your machine is bound to a domain, you could use the Administrator account to log in for troubleshooting/service reasons. It is just like any other account, but with system level authority.

Comment: How long can the Administrator password be?

Comment: Google is a useful tool, utilize it. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/maximum-length-of-password-windows-10

Answer (score 3):

Considering teh concept of defense in depth, a password has to be set for all critical account irrespective of their status. So it is recommended to enable Admin to set up a strong password.

net user Administrator

Ref: http://hardenwindows10forsecurity.com/

Comment: When will that password be used? If there is the Administrator account, the regular admin account, and a standard user account. Thank you.